# How to inject Scala variable into html attribute in Scala template HTML?

Tags: html, scala, playframework, scala-template

Says, I have a variable @index, and I want to name all the checkboxes with suffix `cb_${index}`

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb_$index" value="check" />
</td>
```

The above syntax didn't work at all. Is this even possible in Scala template or am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="cb_@index" value="check" />` ?

Comment: @m-z: Thanks, I'm confusing myself between @ and $. Shame!

Comment: `$` is for string interpolation, which isn't needed here, because really the whole template is a string that's parsed and compiled specially.